# Xbox UWP Memory Usage Limit

Tags: windows, uwp, xbox-one

I have a UWP video player app which runs on Xbox One. The app downloads resources: videos and audio, and then plays once completed. On my laptop, everything works fine and I can play the videos. However on the Xbox, at exactly the same point, I call fopen, which returns a nullptr and`GetLastError()` returning `112 - ERROR_DISK_FULL`.

The total data size is about 7.5GB, but this error occurs less than half way through downloading. Is there some kind of storage limit on the Xbox? I have read this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/system-resource-allocation which says that deployed using Visual Studio these limits don't apply. I am currently using VS to debug the application so this should be possible if it is the reason.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: What disk path are you using?

Comment: Hi Chuck,  the root path is ```U:\Users\UserMgr0\AppData\Local\Packages``` and the folder I am using is LocalState.

Comment: In addition the MemoryManager returns ```AppMemoryUsageLevel``` as low, and the ```AppMemoryUsage``` is way below the limit.

Comment: @pma07pg The document you post is the limitation of the RAM, not the disk space. The issue you meet is a simple one that the disk space of your Xbox is running out.

Comment: Hello Roy, I can confirm this isn't the case. On the Device Portal, on the Performance tab, the 'in use' RAM is about 1.3GB... On my laptop, task manager says it's using around 400MB RAM. I created a simple UWP app which writes N files of size 100mb. At around the 3.8GB mark, I get the same error. There's something else happening, and the ~3.8GB mark matches with when my app seems to stop being able to open new files.

Comment: So you are still writing files to the disk spack to test, right? What is the size of your available disk space?

Comment: Exactly. The Xbox dev mode HDD space is 250GB or so, there's plenty of space for that. The RAM usage 'seems' to be extremely low, based on what task manager says on my laptop and the Xbox says on the Device Portal. The test app which writes the files to disk, does so sequentially and closes the handle after writing each file. There's nothing obvious that could be leading to this error! Bit lost.

Comment: There are multiple disks on Xbox, and the application data folder that you are storing to goes to a drive that they can’t increase, a drive that is NOT the developer drive.  It’s a fixed size.

Comment: Ahh poo, OK. That would explain why I can deploy the files across with Visual Studio but can't download them in app. I guess this is a global hard limit for this drive? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've summarized an answer here. You could make it as answer if you'd like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summary the issue. The error shows that the disk space of the Xbox that is used to store files is running out. What the document mentioned is about the memory limitation, not the disk limitation.

There is only a certain amount of space dedicated for file storage as the drive is split into partitions. Just like an external drive, it can be formatted for file storage or games and apps. It can't hold both. So they split the internal drive so there is some file storage with most of the drive dedicated to the storage of games and apps.

The application data folder that you are storing to goes to a drive that they can’t increase, a drive that is NOT the developer drive. It’s a fixed size.

Comment: Thank you! We'll just have to package the media in the App.